# How in this world can I simplify this $\sqrt 2\cdot(1/(\sqrt2)-1/(\sqrt2)\cdot i)^{31}$ ????

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients, computer-science

I have a problem, obviously. I am doing some maths and now I have to simplify this: $\sqrt 2\cdot(1/(\sqrt2)-1/(\sqrt2)\cdot i)^{31}$ ????. But I just don´t know how ????
I´ve started simplifying by multiplying numerator and denominator with $\sqrt 2$ but that´s it I just can´t go any further because I have really no idea how to continue. So please is there anybody who can help me ? Because i really tried and also google won´t help :D

Comment: Look up de Moivre's theorem.

Comment: Good that you added four question marks!!!! Otherwise nobody would care!!!!

Comment: Those four question marks are there for a purpose.  That purpose is to draw downvotes like mine :-S

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$(x+iy)^n=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}e^{i\arctan2(y,x)}\right)^n \tag 1$$

where $\arctan2(y,x)$ is given [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> Using $(1)$ with $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, and $n=31$, we find that $$\begin{align}\sqrt 2\left(x+iy\right)^{n}&=\sqrt 2\left(\sqrt{\frac12+\frac12}e^{-i\pi/4}\right)^{31}\\\\&=\sqrt {2}e^{-i31\pi/4}\\\\&=1+i\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{31}=$$

---

- $$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right|=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}=1$$
- $$\arg\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right]=-\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

  ---

$$\sqrt{2}\left(e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}\right)^{31}=\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{31\pi i}{4}}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}=1+i$$

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Euler identities?
How about this:
$$\sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)^{31}=\sqrt{2}[\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{4})]^{31}=\sqrt{2}(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})^{31}=\sqrt{2}e^{-i\frac{31\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \left( \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} - \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} i \right)^{31} \\[10pt]
= {} & \underbrace{\left( \cos(-45)^\circ + i\sin(-45^\circ) \right)^{31} = \cos(-31\cdot 45^\circ) + i \sin(-31\cdot45^\circ)}_\text{de Moivre's theorem} \\[10pt]
= {} & \cos(+45^\circ) + i \sin(+45^\circ) = \cdots\cdots
\end{align}
(and then multiply both sides by $\sqrt 2$).